# Handle push notification response when app is killed (App is not running)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, apple-push-notifications

Is there any way to handle push notification response and callback to server,
I need a handler when the push notification comes on the device and the app is killed, and the user did not respond.

Any suggestions for solving this query???

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can make use of Silent Push Notifications in iOS. But you have to enable the background mode for your app.

To make your push notification as silent you have to add the property `content-avaialble` to 1 in push notification payload.

When the app is in suspended state when a silent push notification recieved it will invoke your app and it will put your app in background state.

This method will be called regardless of state of the app

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:
  (NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler 
{
    NSLog(@"Remote download push notification received");
    //Callback to your server here
}
```